# How to get resultant type of multiplying two different types?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, return-type

How would one go about getting the resultant type of multiplying two different types i.e.

```
template< typename TA, typename TB>
struct multiplier
{
    using result_type = // something here finds result of TA * TB
    result_type operator()( TA a, TB b ) const
    {
        return a * b;
    }
};
```

I know in C++ it is perfectly valid to multiply two numerical values of different type and this will give a value in a type that is known to the compiler.  I.e. multiplying a `double` and an `int` will result in a `double` type answer.

As such in a template class where the types are known at compile-time, it should be possible to determine the type that will be created.  Indeed a *lambda* can be created to return the result of this value i.e.

```
auto foo = [](int a, float b){ return a * b;}
auto c = foo( 13, 42.0 );
```

This would cause `c` to be a `float`.

Please note, that I am limited to being able to use only features of [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) or below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `decltype` to do this:

```cpp
using result_type = decltype(std::declval<TA&>() * std::declval<TB&>());
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) and [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) for this.  `decltype` will give you the type of an expression and `std::declval` will "create" an object of the type for you, even if it can't/you don't know how to construct it.  That gives you something like

```
using result_type = decltype(std::declval<TA&>() * std::declval<TB&>());
```

Note that I am using lvalue references for the type.  This is done because by default `decval` will give you an rvalue reference which might give you a different type.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the other answers, if you do not need the `result_type` for later use, but only to specify the return type of the `operator()`, there is another way, by not defining the alias for `result_type` in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

You can provide a *[trailing return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function)* along with [`auto` return](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/11/trailing-return-types-everywhere/) as follows:

```
template< typename TA, typename TB>
struct multiplier
{
    auto operator()(TA a, TB b) const -> decltype(a * b)
//  ^^^^^                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        return a * b;
    }
};
```

**([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b1DcjYj7HBkIZPnX))**